# step-up transformer design - basics

Tags: transformer, piezo

I want to step up Li-ion battery voltage to ~100-125V at ~145kHz and ~0.5Arms.

(The circuit is to drive a small piezo at its ultrasonic resonant frequency.)

I have limited space.

Are there any rules of thumb for picking a *minimal*, suitably sized (toriodal?) core?

At this stage I'm just trying to get a feel for whether this is a viable option.

From @kartman below, I need a core to handle 62.5W of power. But, the core does not dissipate that energy, so joule heating is not the limiting factor. He also mentions 'flux density'.

Looking at sites selling cores, they list values labelled as
"Le Ae Ve", no units and no definitions of the labels.

Essentially, I'm asking how to work out the minimum size of core capable of performing a 33:1 hike in voltage.

If the results would fit into the space available, then this might be a viable thing to pursue. Otherwise I will need to look at an alternative method -- boost converter or similar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to transfer around 50W at 145kHz so at a rough guess the core should fit into a 1” cube. Designing a transformer is an iterative process - you know what flux density is required so you select a core based on that then determine the size required by the windings. That might mean a larger core. Then you can figure out losses. Iterate until you meet your requirements.

Comment: @Kartman By "should fit into a 1" cube", do you mean 'contain 1"³ of core material' distributed into a toroid (say 50mmOD x 30mmID x 14mm thick)? OR 'the core plus windings should fit into a 1"cude? If the latter, this is worth pursuing further; if the former its not. I get how you got the 50W; but what parameter do I look for on a spec sheet to work out if a given core can handle this? (Please see update to OP as I've run out of space here)

Comment: @Community Please clarify your request for clarification. Without you stating what part of my question you are failing to understand, it's hard to tell exactly what you are asking!

Comment: For driving small piezo crytal a boost converter topology will work just fine.here is the core B64290L0044X038 its a very high permeability core and quite small maybe you can stack two of these together for higher power handling capabability.if you want to use transformer than i will recommend a flyback topology you can use a small transformer like the EE25 and add the aditional gap.hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr. Infinite Thanks for the information. The B64290L0044X038 would certainly fit physically, but I'm having trouble gleaning any information from the datasheet(s) I've found regarding its suitability magnetically, and I have doubts that I could get sufficient turns of suitably thick wire around it to achieve the required 33:1 ratio. **Is there anywhere we could discuss this. The whole format of this place is not conducive to interactive discussion.**

Comment: @buk, you’re asking how to design an inductor/ transformer. Not a simple subject, but there are online calculators that will do most of the work for you. Be it boost or flyback the core has to store enough energy and that influences the core size.

Comment: Are you driving the transducer continuously or pulsed?

Comment: @kartman Not exactly. At this stage I'm simply trying to work out if it will fit my limited space; not a fully work out design. I think all I need to know is: what area and volume of core is required to handle the power.  I've done a preliminary design https://i.imgur.com/bx8O2AA.png  that can physically accommodate the turns of required gauge wire, and static analysis shows it would reach a maximum magnetic flux density of 0.23T; which I believe would be fine for a mains transformer...but at 145khZ?

Comment: @qrk The 145kHz signal would flow for a few seconds --  say max. 30s -- but may be repeated every few minutes. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Search for an off the shelf inductor around 1uH >26A

Comment: @kartman An inductor doesn't work as a transformer?????

Comment: @buk then go for a boost topology.why do you want to use the transformer? Any specific reason

Comment: @Mr. Infinite 1) simple, low part count design (flyback converter); 2) isolation of HV from the rest of the circuit. (I think there is also a third reason, but I'm not sure if it will work yet and its really beyond my current level of understanding, so I'm keeping schtum on that. :) )

Comment: @Buk,Alright i have an idea that could help you. can i get more information on the driver circuit?because i have a small U type transformer core and few months ago ive rewinded it and did a lot of testing.i got maximum output of 100watts from that tiny beast.its a very easy to get transformer i will let you know my results and specs soon as possible

Comment: @mr. Infinite The best notion I have at the moment is this http://schmidt-walter-schaltnetzteile.de/smps_e/spwandl_e.png (but it is just a guide) from this site I've just been pointed at http://schmidt-walter-schaltnetzteile.de/smps_e/spw_smps_e.html. I fed in my values Vin_min:3.2 Vin_max: 4.2 Vout: 125 Iout:0.5 f:145kHz and it suggested E20/10/6, which meets my size criteria (just), but its not a toroid, which I think is better.

Comment: @Buk okey then go for the toroid style transformer but in order to store the energy somewhere use a seperate inductor connected in parallel to the primary.click here for more info https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/flyback-transformer-gap-colin-j-tuck&ved=2ahUKEwjTjZLY0sfzAhVWzTgGHQnSDlIQjjh6BAgeEAE&usg=AOvVaw2JCgJDPNcOjfg4AYdYp1xs&cshid=1634137315108

Comment: For the core you can check this out:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ferroxcube.home.pl/prod/assets/tn13755.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiXpMeN1cfzAhXq4jgGHee-CUQQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw06ULF3p0h4iY_PTjRHjFqa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130496/discussion-between-buk-and-mr-infinite).